# Registration in GitHub

Tags: api, github, github-api

I am making an applocation-wrapper on the GitHub API. I want to give users the opportunity to registration through my application, but I do not see the re registration in API documentation. Is it possible, to create an account on GitHub through API?

Comment: How are you authenticating to GitHub? OAuth is probably the best method available to you, which should let users create accounts on the GitHub auth screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible, to create an account on GitHub through API?

No, not possible currently.

However, as mentioned in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587218/registration-in-github#comment58864586_35587218) above, you could implement the OAuth flow:

https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/

If your users don't have a GitHub account, they can create one as a part of the OAuth flow for authorizing your application.